# How to fix "Cannot provide null context for the database" - Android Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm trying to build a Room Database but it says that Context is null even tho I tried the same classes in different application and it works as intended.

```java
@Database(entities = {City.class, User.class}, version = AppDatabase.DB_VERSION, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_db";

    public abstract UserDao userDao();
    public abstract CityDao cityDao();

    public static AppDatabase getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(RoomApp.getAppContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

```java
public class RoomApp extends Application {
    private static WeakReference<RoomApp> appContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appContext = new WeakReference<>(this);

        AppDatabase.getInstance(); //this will init & fill db
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return appContext != null ? appContext.get() : null;
    }
}
```

Whenever I access AppDatabase.getInstance(); I get an error message saying: "Cannot provide null context for the database."

Comment: Why do you use `WeakReference`? Your `Application` is already a singleton, so you don't need to worry about memory leaks. Just assign the `Application` to a static field in `onCreate()` and return it in your getter. Also, where do you call `getInstance()` on your `AppDatabase`?

Comment: Well, I don't call `getInstance()` in the `AppDatabase` class, I call it in `RoomApp`.

Comment: Don't save context in static fields